# DataTables warning: table=userTable - Invalid JSON response?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, datatables, gson

I use jQuery DataTables and get this warning message:

> DataTables warning: table=userTable - Invalid JSON response

A servlet fetch users from MySQL which I want to display in a jQuery Datatable, but Ajax can't parse the JSON or the JSON is generated wrong in servlet?

Servlet:

```
    List<UserDTO> users = this.service.getAllUser();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                request.setAttribute("users", gson.toJson(users));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("listAllUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registered Users</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#userTable').dataTable({
                "processing" : true,
                "serverSide" : true,
                "ajax" : {
                    "url" : "ListAllUserServlet",
                    "type" : "POST"
                },
                "columns" : [ {
                    "data" : "id"
                }, {
                    "data" : "userName"
                }, {
                    "data" : "firstName"
                }, {
                    "data" : "lastName"
                }, {
                    "data" : "email"
                }, {
                    "data" : "phone"
                }, {
                    "data" : "location"
                }, {
                    "data" : "password"
                }, {
                    "data" : "gender"
                }, {
                    "data" : "birthday"
                } ]
            });
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="userTable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="10" id="userList">Users</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>User id</th>
                    <th>User name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Birth date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10"><a href="index.jsp" id="toIndex">Back</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

JSON generated by servlet:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "userName1",
        "firstName": "firstName1",
        "lastName": "lastName1",
        "email": "email1@gmail.com",
        "phone": "36202080085",
        "location": "location1",
        "password": "password1",
        "gender": "m",
        "birthday": "1-02-2015"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are couple issues with your code:

- You have enabled server-side processing mode with `"serverSide": true` but your data is formatted for client-side processing mode instead. Remove `"serverSide": true` to use client-side processing mode.
- You need to use `dataSrc: ""` ash shown below to match your JSON data format, see [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for more information.

  ```
  "ajax" : {
      "url" : "ListAllUserServlet",
      "type" : "POST",
      "dataSrc": ""
  },
  ```

Comment: same error, But if I want to go with serverSide. so how can I. Because if I go with client-side and my data will be coming in lakes, so client browser will be not able to handle?

Comment: Given the above changes, but not worked for me.  Actually, ajax response is not in datatable render format, so that I loop through the data and drew table.Data is showing in table but the above error alert also showing.Need to remove that pop up error alert.

Answer (score 5):

Even though all data are showing correctly and also when you get this warning, it can be handled as,

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function(obj,param,err){
                var tableId = obj.sTableId;
                console.log('Handling DataTable issue of Table '+tableId);
        };
```

Comment: it works because some time hitting ajax return nothing . It is indeed very help full

Comment: it's works first time, But when I use another page there are same error